# Xamarin zoom on selected region

Tags: skiasharp

I need some guidance for this one:

Having a canvasA taking full screen and a smaller canvasB and a customView "pointView":

```
<ContentPage.Content>
       <Grid>
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>

           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

           <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="CanvasA" BackgroundColor="Black" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
           <custom:PointView x:Name="PointView"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
           <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="CanvasB" BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
       </Grid>
   </ContentPage.Content>
```

PointView represents a point that can be moved across CanvasA and anytime its position changes, it raises an event with the new screen coordinates. I'm trying to use the coordinates from this point to create a zoom region on CanvasB. With other words, giving a screen coordinate, I want to create a zoom from that region of CanvasA over CanvasB.

I tried this so far:

The point update event. My region is a square created by adding 10 pixels to each side of the point new coordinates

```
private void PointUpdatedEvent_Arrived(AppGlobals.PointEnum point, Classes.Point newPointCoordinates)
        {
            SKPoint[] arr;
            _miniImagepathToClip = new SKPath();

            arr = new SKPoint[]
            {
                new SKPoint((float) ((newPointCoordinates.X - 10) * DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density), (float) ((newPointCoordinates.Y - 10) * DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density)),
                new SKPoint((float) ((newPointCoordinates.X + 10) * DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density), (float) ((newPointCoordinates.Y - 10) * DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density)),
                new SKPoint((float) ((newPointCoordinates.X + 10) * DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density), (float) ((newPointCoordinates.Y + 10) * DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density)),
                new SKPoint((float) ((newPointCoordinates.X - 10) * DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density), (float) ((newPointCoordinates.Y + 10) * DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density))
            };

            _miniImagepathToClip.AddPoly(arr);
            CanvasB.InvalidateSurface(); // redraw
        }
```

Then I redraw CanvasB. In this function, I'm trying to crop the area delimited by _miniImagepathToClip from the bitmap drawed on CanvasA and draw it on dest region of CanvasB

```
private void CanvasB_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
        {
            SKImageInfo info = e.Info;
            SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
            SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

            miniCanvasWidth = info.Width;
            miniCanvasHeight = info.Height;

            canvas.Clear();

            if (_miniImagepathToClip != null)
            {
                // Crop canvas before drawing image
                canvas.ClipPath(_miniImagepathToClip);
            }

            SKRect dest = new SKRect(0, 0, info.Width, info.Height);

            BitmapStretch stretch = BitmapStretch.AspectFit;
            BitmapAlignment horizontal = BitmapAlignment.Center;
            BitmapAlignment vertical = BitmapAlignment.Start;

            //originalBitmap.Resize(info, SKFilterQuality.High);

            canvas.DrawBitmap(originalBitmap, dest, stretch, horizontal, vertical);
        }
```

But my result is always an empty canvas (see picture, red rectangle being CanvasB)

[image: Screenshot]

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong? If I make CanvasB be the same size as CanvasA, it's working as expected